# Why is my ArrayList throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException exception?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing this method to create a shuffled deck of cards:

```
public static ArrayList<String> shuffle() {
    String cards[] = {"Two of Spades","Three of Spades","Four of Spades","Five of Spades", "Six of Spades","Seven of Spades", "Eight of Spades", "Nine of Spades", "Ten of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Spades", 
                      "Two of Hearts","Three of Hearts","Four of Hearts","Five of Hearts", "Six of Hearts","Seven of Hearts", "Eight of Hearts", "Nine of Hearts", "Ten of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Hearts",
                      "Two of Clubs","Three of Clubs","Four of Clubs","Five of Clubs", "Six of Clubs","Seven of Clubs", "Eight of Clubs", "Nine of Clubs", "Ten of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs", "Ace of Clubs", 
                      "Two of Diamonds","Three of Diamonds","Four of Diamonds","Five of Diamonds", "Six of Diamonds","Seven of Diamonds", "Eight of Diamonds", "Nine of Diamonds", "Ten of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds", "Ace of Diamonds" };
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        int index = randomizer.nextInt(numbers.size());
        int number = numbers.get(index);
        deck.add(numbers.get(number), cards[i]);
        numbers.remove(index);
    }
    return deck;
}
```

My issue here is that on the deck.add, i'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException exception. I thought the ArrayList would resize to fit. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:473)
    at game.mainGame.shuffle(mainGame.java:182)
    at game.mainGame.main(mainGame.java:32)
```

Comment: You need to work out if the index error is caused by the `deck.add`, the `numbers.get(number)` or the `cards[i]`. It'll be one of them, but it's hard for us to magically see which one.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought I mentioned - it's the deck.add, that's where the exceptions being thrown.

Comment: This is another good example of "Don't re-invent the wheel". Using `Collections.shuffle()` instead, as Ted Hopp already mentioned [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30795000/1744230), will save you a lot of trouble ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for the exception. One is that you are double-indexing into the `numbers` list in these two lines:

```
int number = numbers.get(index);
deck.add(numbers.get(number), cards[i]);
```

The problem is that once you have removed a number from `numbers`, then there's a good chance that one of the remaining numbers is larger than the largest legal index. (In fact, this is guaranteed unless you happen to generate the indexes in strictly descending order.) The other reason is given in [the answer by @default locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795021/535871): you cannot add to arbitrary positions in `deck`; the two-argument `add()` call will generate this exception if you attempt to add an element at a position greater than the current length of the list.

Rather than implementing your own shuffle, I suggest that you simply use `Collections.shuffle(List)` to randomize the `numbers` list (or, better, the deck itself).

Here's my version of `shuffle()`:

```
private static final List<String> cards = Arrays.asList(
    "Two of Spades","Three of Spades","Four of Spades","Five of Spades", "Six of Spades","Seven of Spades", "Eight of Spades", "Nine of Spades", "Ten of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Spades", 
    "Two of Hearts","Three of Hearts","Four of Hearts","Five of Hearts", "Six of Hearts","Seven of Hearts", "Eight of Hearts", "Nine of Hearts", "Ten of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Hearts",
    "Two of Clubs","Three of Clubs","Four of Clubs","Five of Clubs", "Six of Clubs","Seven of Clubs", "Eight of Clubs", "Nine of Clubs", "Ten of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs", "Ace of Clubs", 
    "Two of Diamonds","Three of Diamonds","Four of Diamonds","Five of Diamonds", "Six of Diamonds","Seven of Diamonds", "Eight of Diamonds", "Nine of Diamonds", "Ten of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds", "Ace of Diamonds"
);

public static ArrayList<String> shuffle() {
    final ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>(cards);
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
    return deck;
}
```

Comment: One more problem is that `Random` object is recreated on every loop iteration, thus randomization will be not very effective.

Answer (score 2):

Method [ArrayList.add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) puts `element` on the specified position `index`.
Method throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`- if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

```
deck.add(numbers.get(number), cards[i]);
```

Since your arraylist `deck` is empty (size()=0) at the beginning you can only add elements on index 0, for any other index exception will be thrown.

You might want to generate random cards rather than random positions. Check out previous answers for alternative suggestions for shuffling.

Comment: +1. The exception is more likely to be for this reason than the one I first offered up in my answer (not that my reason was wrong, just much less likely).

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks, your answer is absolutely correct and contains useful suggestions. I just wanted to highlight another possible reason for exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with deck.add(indexA,objectB) method, because you are trying to place a card in deck at the indexA which may not be present. i.e The value of indexA must be between 0 and deck.size(). You need to change your code logic.

java doc link for reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Change for loop like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        int index = randomizer.nextInt(numbers.size());
        int number = numbers.get(index);
        deck.add(cards[number]);
        numbers.remove(index);
    }
```